# GWTupload performance

Tags: performance, gwt, file-upload, upload

Is there anyone checked the performance of gwtupload. I want to switch from my normal fileUpload to gwtupload just scared about the performance as there will be lot of ping from client to server to check the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a demo [here](http://chrisachilli.it:8080/ebt-admin/)

Just click on a link on the left side and upload any file the size you want and u'll see for yourself. Actually, I still haven't investigated if there' a chance to speed it up. I guess so.
Just be advised that the demo won't be there forever ;)